# C/C++ map binary data to struct members

Tags: c++, c, data-binding, reflection, string

Lets say, I have the following text file:

**Listing 1:**

```
Endianess=little
AddressModel=32

typedef struct{
  int    x;
  int    y;
  float  f;
  double d;
} A;

instance1:0x0000000100000002000048C19A99999999993C40
instance2:0x00100257000000090000000FBA99359976992397
```

Where instance1 corresponds to an instance of struct A, such as:

**Listing 2:**

```
A->x = 0x00000001         = 1
A->y = 0x00000002         = 2
A->f = 0x000048C1         = -12.5
A->d = 0x9A99999999993C40 = 28.6
```

**The Task:**

Write an application that takes as a text file, an arbitrary C data structure, and an arbitrary memory dump, and print out in an easy-to-read format, a reconstruction of the instance of that struct (such as what is seen in Listing 2).

**The Questions:**

1. What is the best way to do this?
2. Rather than re-invent the wheel, is(are) there any Open-source solutions that this problem might benefit from?

**Things to consider:**

The solution will have to

1. take into account the length of the datatype.
2. handle different address models and endianness.
3. display both hex, and a native display for that particular data type.
4. take C structs that were NOT linked into the program you are writing.

**Bonus Question:**

Handle a case with embedded structs:

```
typedef struct{
  int    q;
  int    p;
  A      a;  //embedded struct of type A defined in listing 1
} B;
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you got so far? Where are you stuck at, exactly?

Comment: This sounds like a really useful little program.

Comment: Do you already know how to get the offsets and lengths of the `struct` fields?

Comment: I have to agree- the wording of the question makes it stink like a copy and paste of an assignment.

Comment: The instances are also buggy -- they aren't in little-endian format, and don't have the necessary padding before `A::d`.

Comment: Its not an assignment, an assignment at any school would DEFINATELY not be this complicated. Also if it was for school, I probably won't be able to re-use existing libraries. Its for a debugging solution. I have tried using a lexer, and some really nasty hardcoded bits, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Jeremiah, ya sorry, the instances were for show, I didn't think computing proper values was necessary.

Comment: without knowing the endianness or the size of the struct there are too many possible answers.

Comment: @Argote, well the endianness and the address model would be included in the text file (see listing 1)

Comment: @ Jeremiah, yes assume you know the offsets and padding, and for data length, assume it can be calculated from the address model, with standard C data types in windows (ie for 32bit, int=DWORD, double=QWORD, etc). for embedded structs, you could calculate the size by counting the individual members

Comment: @J T ah ok, I thought you would just get the instances

Comment: "take C structs that were NOT linked into the program you are writing.". So what, the answerer is writing the program now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use reflection in C or C++ so that's out. That means you will need to write a parser than can read C struct definitions. Not hard at all really.

You can do it yourself if you want: tokenizing and parsing C is not hard. Or you could use tools like lex and yacc. Or you could use a C++ library like Boost Spirit.

Once you've got a parser then you can build the data reader in C. You don't want to reproduce the struct in your C code. You just want to be able to read it properly.

I would write an array of data types and names during the parse step. During the binary read step, step through the array and read however many bytes you need to read, then produce the output line. Repeat until you run out of data types in the array.

Comment: If the problem is to dump one or more instances of the same flat struct data type from a binary file, then yes this should be pretty easy.   If the "data dump" is really an image dump from a real program, then one might to have have all the program data types and something to climb throught the data, and then the problem is a lot harder.

Comment: @ Ira, no the data would be for instances of variables themselves, not the entire stack of an application or anything like that.

Comment: @Ira: I seem to recall that there are some neat addons to DDD to visualize data structures including things like linked lists, C++ STL containers and other things. A debugger is the thing to use if reading program dumps.